# User authentication and dynamic routing in traefik

Tags: docker, haproxy, traefik

I want to replace haproxy with traefik. But in order to that, I have to replace a Lua script which handles authentication (via auth token calling a rest API) and custom redirect (certain docker service) depending on headers and authentication from before. 
Is there an (easy) way to that?

Right now as for migrating I was thinking to leave haproxy for now and routing all valid traffic to traefik.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Also extremely interested.

Comment: Saw your comment just now ; ) .. 2 years later
So we switched to `istio` for now, which able to this quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication and Traefik is not an easy thing. At my company, we just switched back from Traefik to nginx since handling ldap/kerberos/pki etc. With Traefik can be painfully awkward. There is the possibility to pass authentication on from Traefik to a 3rd party and collect the session token or other relevant information using [Forward Auth](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/forwardauth/), so maybe take a look at that. You can also use [BasicAuth](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/basicauth/)
 Although getting it to run with your setup might prove hacky.